# Uexpected output dimension in keras cnn network

Tags: python, numpy, keras

For some reason am I getting an uexpected output dimension for my classification network.

The network has 18 inputs of shape (45,5,3)

And the output is a vector of length 15 - one class for each third of 45.  The extracted classes comes from a pool of 145 classes.

My network looks like this:

```
#stride = 2
#dim = 40
#window_height = 5
#splits = ((40-5)+1)/2 = 18

kernel_number = int(math.ceil(splits))
list_of_input = [Input(shape = (45,5,3)) for i in range(splits)]
list_of_conv_output = []
list_of_max_out = []
for i in range(splits):
    list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = kernel_number , kernel_size = (int(splits-3),3))(list_of_input[i]))
    list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))

merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)
print merge.shape
reshape = Reshape((15,324))(merge)

dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(units = 145 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)
model = Model(inputs = list_of_input ,outputs = dense3)
```

But for some reason am I getting an error when I passing my output data. 
It is currently stored as numpy.ndarray of shape (16828,15) and I get an value error stating:

```
Error when checking model target: expected dense_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (16828, 15)
```

Why is it expected 3 dim rather than 2 dim?

The model summary states that the output dim is (15,145) as I also would expect?  15 classes from a pool of 145 classes.  Or is this incorrect?

Model summary: 
https://pastebin.com/27YTQW2m

Comment: What is the result of `print merge.shape`?

Comment: @Van (?, 15, 1, 324)

Comment: What is your output array storing? Integers? And what is your `loss` function?

Comment: Haven't decided anything regarding the loss... So will try out with SGD, an see from there..  but a vector with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was corrected, the `model.output_shape` is `(None, 15, 145)` and you sent an array with shape `(16828, 15)` during training.

Your might want to expand `(16828, 15)` to `(16828, 15, 145)` before fitting it.